# Separate Meta per Stack Exchange community?

Tags: support, meta

Why is there a Meta page for each site? From what I gather, Meta is all about asking and getting information that has to do with the technical side of Stack Exchange, and can be relevant for each site, so why have them separate?

Comment: You can visit each site's `help/whats-meta` page to know more. For eg.: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A lot of the questions on meta are about specific issues on the main site:

- Why was this question closed?
- Why isn't this question closed?
- What happened here?
- Can these two tags be merged.
- etc.

which wouldn't be of interest to the vast majority of users on a global meta site.

In fact this was one of the reasons this child meta and Meta Stack Exchange were split.

Answer (score 9):

Most questions about policy, questions, answers and tags won't fit on a network-wide Meta, so that's why there are per-site metas. But there is a network-wide Meta ([Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com/)), for questions/bugs/feature-requests about the whole network.